# Firebase not taking all arguments

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

My code goes as followed. 
Once I get to the part where I am writing to the database it seems to skip over ContestName. Then it will record the contestdescription and user to the database. If I put contestDescription first before contestName then the contestDescription is missed but the name gets stored. Really funky bug. Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: I tried a sleep but that didn't help at all.

```
@IBAction func SubmitContest(_ sender: Any) {

//Convert to text
        let contesttitle = ContestName.text;
        let contestdescript = ContestDescription.text;

//Some Firebase Stuff
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let contestRef = ref.child("craftType").child("Custom")
        let thisContest = contestRef.childByAutoId()

//Store to firebase
//Whatever one is first is not making it to firebase database
        thisContest.setValue(["ContestName": contesttitle])
        thisContest.setValue(["ContestDescription": contestdescript])
        thisContest.child("User").setValue(userID)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `setValue` on a location replaces all existing data at that location. So in this snippet:

```
thisContest.setValue(["ContestName": contesttitle])
thisContest.setValue(["ContestDescription": contestdescript])
```

The second line is replacing whatever the first line writes.

You should either combine the two:

```
thisContest.setValue(["ContestName": contesttitle, "ContestDescription": contestdescript])
```

Or [use `updateChildValues`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) (which doesn't replace the entire data at the location, but only at the properties you specify):

```
thisContest.updateChildValues(["ContestName": contesttitle])
thisContest.updateChildValues(["ContestDescription": contestdescript])
```